# Total Overlapping Time

Tags: excel, vba, time, overlap

I work for a company that runs online customer service chat. Each employee can take up to two chats at once.  I need to find the total amount of time each employee spends in 'double chats' each day.  I intend to do this by adding up the overlapping time for each chat. However, since multiple chats can happen at the same time and there is no limit on how short or long a chat may run, a single long chat may be overlapped by several shorter ones.  That's where I've run into trouble. I've found this code which finds overlapping hours:

```
    Sub intersectHours()
Dim a As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, ohrs As Double
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        ohrs = 0: Set rng = Nothing
        For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            If j <> i And Not Intersect(.Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "D").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "E").Value2) - 1), _
                 .Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "D").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "E").Value2) - 1)) Is Nothing Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = Intersect(.Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "D").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "E").Value2) - 1), _
                                    .Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "D").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "E").Value2) - 1))
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, Intersect(.Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "D").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "E").Value2) - 1), _
                                                   .Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "D").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "E").Value2) - 1)))
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For a = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
                ohrs = ohrs + TimeSerial(rng.Areas(a).Rows.Count, 0, 0)
            Next a
        End If
        '.Cells(i, 6).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
        .Cells(i, 6) = ohrs
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

However, my data is in h:mm:ss format, so the overlapping time output should be measured in the same.  The code above only outputs hours and I don't know enough about VBA to adapt it to my purpose.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in WFM myself and I too have to account for concurrency.  I've already built reporting for this very situation.  However, I primarily use excel formulas and a pivot table to represent the data after a little processing from VBA

There are two ways I can think of your data being represented, and you haven't specified which, so I'll provide a solution for each.

**The data is stored with start and stop time in each row.**

Assuming that each row is A is agent ID, B is chat ID, C is start, D is stop.  You will want to convert this to event type reporting.  The following code does this by adding stop events to the bottom of the data, and converting the existing data into start time events.

```
Dim h As Long: h = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("A" & h + 1 & ":B" & h + h - 1).Value = Range("A2:B" & h).Value
Range("C" & h + 1 & ":C" & h + h - 1).Value = Range("D2:D" & h).Value
Range("D2:D" & h).Value = 1
Range("D" & h + 1 & ":D" & h + h - 1).Value = -1
Range("C1").Value = "Timestamp"
Range("D1").Value = "Type"
```

**The data is stored as event-based.**

If I assume that column A is Agent ID, B is Chat ID, C is Timestamp, and D is Start/Stop.  Sort by Agent ID (A) ascending, then Timestamp (C) ascending, then add formulas.  Code below:

```
Dim h As Long: h = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("A2:A" & h), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("C2:C" & h), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Range("E1").Value = "Concurrency"
Range("E2:E" & h).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4+IF(RC1=R[-1]C1,R[-1]C5)"
Range("F1").Value = "isConcurrent"
Range("F2:F" & h).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC5>0"
Range("G1").Value = "Duration"
Range("G2:G" & h).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C1=RC1,R[1]C3-RC3,0)"
```

Column E gets the number of chats currently in progress, adding one when a new chat starts, and subtracting when one ends.  Column F checks if there is at least one chat in progress.  Column G checks if that row and the next are the same agent, and if so, gets the time difference.

Once this is all in, pivot the result.  Now you can can represent duration per agent and by concurrency level (EX: 1 chat vs 2 chats) along with agent and group totals.  Again, I do this exact same task myself, and this is the way I do it.

Comment: This works great!  I just had to format my data a bit to get it to work.  The program we use formats all the data as text before creating the report.  I just had to write the time stamps to the same cell to get Excel to auto-format them to DateTime.

Comment: If this works for you, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it as your answer :)